# pre-populating form field from database with "second level" association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have three models: Appointment, Client, and InsuranceProvider

A client has_many :appointments

And a client has_many :insurance_providers (the idea being I"d like to store historical info there).

in my view to create a new appointment, I have this (among other things):

```
<%= f.association :client, label_method: lambda { |c| "#{c.first_name} #{c.last_name}" }, collection: current_user.clients  %>
```

this is fine, but I'd like to get to the copay field in insurance_providers.

Basically, this is how you'd get there:

```
appointment.client.insurance_provider.copay
```

What I'd like to do is pre-populate the "copay amount" field based on the client selected from the dropdown.

How can I do this?

Please let me know if you need to see my models or views explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a second select to be populated with values based on the value in the association.

Basically, you need JQuery/AJAX to do this for you.  JQuery to watch the first select, and then AJAX to get data from rails based on the value chosen, and JQuery again to add values to the second select.

An alternative would be to use an in-place editor like [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) for each select, which would do the AJAX-y stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to to fetch the values for copay based on the return of the select.

Because there are a lot of steps, I'll lay them out, but you can find them in probably a dozen other SO questions.

Add the Javascript, this coffeescript but it's just your basic on change -> send-data call - so change at will.

```
#appointment.js.coffee
$(document).ready ->
  $(".client_select").on "change", ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/appointments/new"
      type: "GET"
      dataType: "script"
      data:
        client: $(".client_select").val()
```

Make sure your form has the 2 jquery elements to get data from and push data to.

```
# First the field to pull from
<%= f.association :client, label_method: lambda { |c| "#{c.first_name} #{c.last_name}" }, collection: current_user.clients, input_html: { class: 'client_select' }  %>

# And then the field to push to
<%= f.input :copay_amount, input_html: { class: 'copay_from_client' } %>
```

This is going to make a request on your "new" action of your `appointments` controller, so you'll need to add a javascript respond to to make sure it can render the next step, the UJS file.

```
# appointments_controller.rb
def new
  # ... All the stuff you're normally doing and additionally:
  #you'll have to adjust the params argument to match your select field
  insurance_copay = Client.find(params[:client]).insurance_provider.copay
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.js { render "new",  locals:{insurance_copay: insurance_copay} }
    format.json { render json: @appointment }
  end 
end
```

Now add the UJS, `new.js.erb`

```
$(".copay_from_client").val('<%= @insurance_copay %>');
```

Comment: previously my new method just cointained this: `@appointment = Appointment.new`. Should this be replaced by what you have or should it be the last line after what you provided?

Comment: also, copay_amount is not part of the Appointment model. Appointments belongs_to Client which has_many InsuranceProviders. So, it's a second level association.

Comment: This isn't working and I don't have enough context here to even tell you what's going wrong. Can you give me any more information?

Comment: Are you saying you want to input values for InsuranceProviders on the same form as Appointment?

Comment: No, I want to grab the current copay value from InsuranceProvider for the client the Appointment is being created before and pre-populate the (appointment's) copay field with that value. And then store that value into the Appointment table. This is in case a single appointment has a higher co-pay value for some reason. Since this won't happen often, i'd like to prepoulate the field with what it most likely is (i.e. copay value from InsuranceProvider). ...did that make any sense?